# Convert .txt file to variables in python

Tags: python

Is there a way to convert a .txt file into a list, + save the list into variables at once?
for example : 
if the .txt file looks like this :

```
Blue,color,sky
Red,color,blood
Dog,animal,bark
```

How do I make it save as

```
Things = {Blue,Red,Dog}
Types = {color,animal}
Related = {sky,blood,bark}
```

Thanks for the help..

Comment: Read the file, parse it into individual tokens, (blue, dog, animal etc), then assign it to a variable. What have you tried?

Comment: there is no special method for this. But you could keep this as `JSON` or `YAML` (or `Pickle`) and then it will be easier.

Comment: you have data in `CSV` format so you can try `csv` module or even simpler `pandas` module.

Comment: @furas - I can't image what json or yaml have to do with this. OP has a text file and wants to parse it. She never said anything about where this file came from or reserializing to a different file. Just turn the columns into sets.

Comment: @tdelaney OP doesn't say it can't use other format. And OP may not know that there are better formats to keep data. Comment is good place for this type of information.

Comment: @furas - They are not necessarily better. CSV is a popular data type that is used in many places and is frequently easy to read and write.

Answer (score 4):

Go through the text, strip each line and split it on `','`, unpack that and send it to `zip`, `map` that to `set`, and unpack the assignment.

```
>>> text = '''Blue,color,sky
... Red,color,blood
... Dog,animal,bark'''.splitlines() # text can also be a file object
>>> things, types, related = map(set, zip(*(i.strip().split(',') for i in text)))
>>> things
{'Dog', 'Blue', 'Red'}
>>> types
{'color', 'animal'}
>>> related
{'blood', 'bark', 'sky'}
```

Comment: Great answer, but just to keep things clear with OP, how about an example that opens a file?

Comment: @tdelaney - It'd just be `with open('file.txt') as text:`, covered in any tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You have data in `CSV` format so you could use `pandas`
(but maybe it is too powerfull module for this small problem)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(filename, names=['Things', 'Types', 'Related'])
```

and then you can use

```
things = set(df['Things'])
types = set(df['Types'])
related = set(df['Related'])
```

Full working example using `StringIO` to create file-like object which emulate real file.

```
import pandas as pd

import io

data = '''Blue,color,sky
Red,color,blood
Dog,animal,bark'''

f = io.StringIO(data)

df = pd.read_csv(f, names=['Things', 'Types', 'Related'])

print(df)

things = set(df['Things'])
types = set(df['Types'])
related = set(df['Related'])

print(things)
print(types)
print(related)
```

result

```
  Things   Types Related
0   Blue   color     sky
1    Red   color   blood
2    Dog  animal    bark

{'Blue', 'Red', 'Dog'}
{'animal', 'color'}
{'bark', 'sky', 'blood'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define list holding the accepted values for Things, Related and Types

```
accepted_things = ["Blue", "Red", "Dog"]
accepted_related = ["Sky", "Blood", "Bark"]

things = []
related = []
//Same for Types

with open(file_path, "r") as file :
        for line in file :
            results = line.split(",")
            //Open file, loop through each line and separate values with comma
            for i in results 
                if i in accepted_things :
                   things.append(i)
                elif i in accepted_related :
                   related.append(i)
```

Maybe not the most elegant solution, but will get the job done perfectly.